# Can computing tan(x)=sin(x)/cos(x) cause a loss of precision?

Tags: performance, floating-point, precision, trigonometry, scientific-computing

After a call to `sincos(x,&s,&c)` from the unix `m` math library it would be natural to get the tangent as `s/c`. Is this safe or there may be (ill) cases in which the (supposedly) more expensive `tan(x)` should be preferred due to precision issues?

Comment: What exactly do you consider "loss of precision"? Can you narrow down what you consider "safe"? How much additional error in `sin()/cos(x)` compared to `tan(x)` is acceptable in your use case?

Comment: Depending on where you get that cosine, it may have a large relative error near pi/2, which since it's a tiny number that you divide by translates to a large absolute error in the tangens.

Comment: @njuffa I guess that depends on the specific application, but as I'm more worried about disasters than extreme precision let's fix a threshold at 1e-6 relative deviation with doubles.

Comment: @harold I edited the question specifying the origin of the cosine.

Comment: I assume you mean `libm`? There are any number of `libm` implementations. Assuming the `libm` in question implements `sincos()` such that the sine and the cosine are computed accurately (with an error bound of a couple of ulps at most) across the entire input domain, than yes, computing `tan(x)` as `sin(x)/cos(x)` is safe, but the maximum ulp error would typically be slightly larger than that of `tan(x)` itself due to additional round-off error from the division. For `float` data, this is easy to show by exhaustive test.

Comment: @MarkDickinson nope, everything I keep doing is wrong. Disregard everything.

Answer (score 0):

If the error in sin(x) is es, and the error in cos(x) is ec, then the error in t=(sin(x)/cos(x) is

```
et = abs(t)*sqrt((es/sin(x))^2 + (ec/cos(x))^2)
```

The error in sin, cos and tan should be right around the precision of the number representation times the value, perhaps a bit or two off. Since the error will track with the precision of the number, the above equation reduces to

```
et = sqrt(es^2 + ec^2)
```

and es and ec should be close to each other. So, the total error from using sin/cos as opposed to a new calculation of the tangent should be about a factor of sqrt(2) greater than the error from calculating the tangent directly.

That assumes the error in sin, cos and tan are all about the same, but that's a pretty good assumption these days. There is a small wobble in error over the range of the function, but that should be handled using some extended precision bits during the calculation, and should not show up significantly in the values you see.

Whether this matters, of course, depends on the situation.

See http://lectureonline.cl.msu.edu/~mmp/labs/error/e2.htm for a decent quick-and-dirty intro to error propagation, which is a good way to tackle this sort of question.

Comment: How does this formula account for error contributed by the division?

Comment: This answer totally neglects the tricks of floating point algebra, which were the origin of my concerns.

Comment: Actually, this answer is specifically _about_ the tricks of floating-point algebra. There is an inherent error in any floating-point calculation. In the best case (which is generally what you see for good floating-point trig functions) the error is caused by the limited precision of the floating-point number. This error propagates through the algebra based on well understood rules of error propagation. The reference I cited gives a very brief introduction to the topic. It specifically deals with the error as it propagates through the division operation.